# Realm architecture pattern

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, realm

I migrated my app from CoreData and I'm deeply impressed how simple things can be. I could delete a lot of code :)

One thing that makes me feel a bit uncomfortable is that Realm spreads all over my application creating a big dependency: My app has a MVVM architecture and I would feel best if only the model would be the place where Realm lives.

Just after the migration I send Result and List objects to my view models. Wouldn't it be better to have [Type] objects instead?

What do you think? How do you structure your apps with realm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to make your own decision on whether having Realm as a dependency is too much of a risk in the architecture, but there are a couple good reasons why you should use the Realm objects/collections directly:

1. Realm is not built on SQLite and is not an ORM. As a result, when you access a Realm object or a collection, that data is memory mapped and lazy loaded only when accessed. This means that if you want to convert a Result into a Swift array of `Objects`, or worse copies of those `Objects` into a class not dependent on Realm, then this will result in reading/copying all the data upfront that is in the `Result`, versus the efficient manner Realm does for you.
2. By default, Realm instances auto-update. What this means is that by using a Realm `Object` or `Result` directly you can bind your view or in your case view model to changes on those objects. Realm instances send out notifications when they are updated  ([relevant docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications)), allowing you to update the view model and then the view off of this (for example if you have a table view backed by a `Result`, you can trigger a `reloadData` on the table view off of the notification, since the `Result` instance will now have the latest objects). Or you can also use Key-Value Observing on a specific Realm object to respond to changes on its properties to update the view/view model ([relevant docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#key-value-observation)).

Hopefully this helps shape your thoughts on architecture. As of writing this post, we are working on object-level notifications that will enable further data-binding capabilities. You can follow the progress on this [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/601).